# How to search by specific pattern in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have below pattern of data in field

`XXX-XX-XXX`

Some of the data don't have that patterns.

So need to search those records.

```
SELECT *  FROM table WHERE `name` NOT REGEXP '^.{10}$'
SELECT *  FROM table WHERE `name` NOT REGEXP '^..........$'
```

Above 2 queries works fine. But not 100%.

Can I filter by `{3}-{2}-{3}` ?

Comment: Do you mean `REGEXP '^[^-]{3}-[^-]{2}-[^-]{3}$'`? Any char but `-` between `-` chars?

Comment: `Example Record: 1E1-CC-FC9`

Comment: So, any alnum? `REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]{3}-[[:alnum:]]{2}-[[:alnum:]]{3}$'`

Comment: Yes any Alpahnumeric in between -. No special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match a string with 3 alphanumeric chars followed with `-`, followed with 2 alphanumeric and then again a hyphen and 3 last alphanumeric in the string.

Use

```
'^[[:alnum:]]{3}-[[:alnum:]]{2}-[[:alnum:]]{3}$'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `[[:alnum:]]{3}` - 3 alphanumeric chars
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[[:alnum:]]{2}-` - 2 alphanumeric chars and a `-`
- `[[:alnum:]]{3}` - 3 alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

See [MySQL "Regular Expression Syntax"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax):

> **Character Class Name   Meaning**
>   `alnum`                               Alphanumeric characters

Comment: Well, that's the first time I hear of `[:alnum:]`. +1 for that :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I added a link to MySQL regex syntax reference, you can see the whole POSIX character class table there.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but it isn't only for MySQL, right? Or is it? Also, it's equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9]`, right?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed You may use either with MySQL's `REGEXP`, I think.  Up to you which one you like more.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed In general, the `[:alnum:]` POSIX character class might match Unicode letters and digits, too, but it depends on the library, flags, etc.